# how to update colleda file vertiex in a-frame

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe

below code can update the color to colleda model but how we manage the vertices dimensions and update to model......for ex we put the dimension in any file(.js etc) and than access into a-frame work below method and put x,y,z values

```
function update_hair_style(verticesdimensionarray){
 alert("update hair")
    var model = document.querySelector('#hairmodel');
    <!-- console.log(model); -->
    var mesh =  model.getObject3D('mesh');
      <!-- console.log(mesh) -->
      mesh.traverse(function(o) {
       <!-- console.log(o) -->
        <!-- console.log("-------------------------------------------------"); -->
       if (o instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
            console.log(o.geometry.vertices)
            //o.material.color = {  r: r, g: g, b: b };
        }else{
            <!-- console.log("ELSE");    -->
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just edit the vertices directly, using the `o.geometry.vertices` that you mention. After editing vertices, you'll need to set `o.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;`.

If that's not what you're looking for, could you expand your answer to explain specifically what you mean by "manage the vertices dimensions", or what's not working from your included code?